# How should I instantiate an object which use external const require

Tags: javascript, oop, electron, node-serialport

I've two files which one representing Connection and DataAcquisition object.
The code below works fine:

```
    class Connection{
       constructor(){
          this.serialConnection = require ('serialport');
       }
    }
```

In another file i have

```
    class DataAcquisiton{
       constructor(){
          this.connection = new Connection();
       }
    }
```

What I'm searching for is don't use de require inside of the first constructor. When I do this:

```
    const serialConnection = require (...);
    class Connection{
       constructor(){
       }
    }
```

It's not possible to instantiate this class within another one. I tried to export as default, and nothing works. May anyone help me?

Comment: What is the problem you get when trying to use the 2nd example?

Comment: @junvar with the second approach If I don't use de export and import method, Connection it's not recognized in the second file. If I use it, the following error shows on console: Unexpected token export (line of export default class) and Unexpected identifier ( on import statement)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
const serialConnection = require (...);
class Connection{
   constructor(){
      this.serialConnection = serialConnection;
   }
}
```

Comment: thx for reply. With this approach should I export the class? At my first example, it works without any export.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade any time you want to use something from another file, you need to export it.

Comment: @Evert that is assuming a module or CommonJS type usage of files. Should OP use an old school files concatenation or successive front script loading without scoping (as is probably the case since they mention their first example works as is), they still do not need to explicitly export.

Comment: @ghybs the first example uses `require` too though, just inline which is kinda bad.

Comment: @Evert indeed OP is very probably mixing file loading methods, which is also not very elegant, but still works with associated setup.